# about simple interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John invested certain sum in the three different schemes $P$,$Q$ and $R$ with rates of interest $10$% per annum and $12$% per annum and $15$% per annum respectively. If total interest accrued in 1 year was $\$3200$ and the amount invested in scheme $R$ was $150$% of the amount invested in scheme $Q$. what was the amount invested in scheme $Q$?

Comment: The solution will not be unique, since we can simply choose to invest everything in $P$ or nothing at all in $P$.

Comment: It seems that you have three unknowns but only two linear equation, so the solution is not unique. Or you know something other?

Comment: need more equations, question uncomplete

Comment: Google Books https://www.google.ca/search?q=If+total+interest+accrued+in+1+year+was+%243200++and+the+amount+invested+in+scheme+R&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1, finds several instances of this question as a multiple-choice question, with "Cannot be determined" as one choice...

Answer (score 0):

Since we invest $\$32000$ in scheme $P$ we have an interest of $\$3200$ in $1$ year, and we have $150\%$ of $\$0$ is $\$0$, so we fulfill the requirement.

Therefore, the answer is $\$0$.